# Multi threading a "ServerRoom" to hold multiple while(true) looped servers

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

I am finishing an assignment for a project and my team has ran into a small bump. We wanted to initially run the program in VM's that would be set up on a network emulated by GNS3, though due to multiple clones errors, RAM errors, and such, have aborted the current idea to simply display a "client server", "dns server" and "web server" on a local host.

I am dedicated to working on the web server and need to create a series of 6 web servers for the dns to send the client to. While the servers are made, I don't know how to correctly run 6 servers that are constantly listening for requests under "one mainFrame" server to direct incoming requests to the correct server.

To make sure the web server can adequately handle large number of hosts, I wrapped the web servers, which became more of handlers, in a multi-thread server than handles the request and creates a new thread for the request to be handled, where the original web server is created to handle it.

I attempted this same method with the mainFrame to create a series of multi thread servers within a single thread, but only end up getting stuck inside one of the multi thread server as it is on a constant "while(true)" loop for listening to connections.

I also looked into Executioners, but can't correctly use them using only server Sockets, though it may have worked if the overall program was wrapped inside a http server object.

[initiating the multi thread server constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGGss.png)

[initiating the client's personal web server within the multi threaded server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXLqL.png)

[Attempting to initiate the multi server, Server, to help handle incoming request within a single IDE instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10woe.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is? *I don't know how to correctly run 6 servers that are constantly listening for requests* - You run 6 servers by starting your server software on 6 different computers. *under "one mainFrame" server to direct incoming requests to the correct server* - You've lost me. Where did this mainframe come from and how is it related to requests arriving at the 6 servers? In what way does it "direct" the requests?

Comment: Sure, so, our group does not have access to 6 different systems right now as our school is not allowing anyone to utilize the labs. We had planned on putting all 6 servers on different VM hosts, but due to issues with GNS3 processing VM's, had to move to local host. I am trying to put all 6 servers, onto one server, so only one machine is needed and each server has a variable to pretend it has an ip address. With all 6 servers running on a single IDE instance, i needed to create another server for connections to this instance to delegate which server the client needs directing to.

Comment: Alright, you don't need 6 separate pieces of hardware, or virtual machines. What you do need is 6 IP addresses so that load balancing through DNS will work. You can set up all IPs in the same host no problem. The server applications instances would each use a real IP address of their own

Comment: Or, are you moving away from the design that uses DNS to distribute the requests to the servers?

Comment: Actually yes, we developed a design that used ports instead of IP addresses. the DNS server was able to direct the client browser to the correct "web server", all six running on local host using separate ports. We were able to configure this and finish testing this morning. Thanks for the suggestions anyways!